# Connect Puppeteer and Browserless Docker Container

Tags: puppeteer

I have two containers, one Puppeteer and one Browserless. I try to connect to Browserless, but it fails. Both containers are in the same network.

Here is my code:

```
await puppeteer.connect({
  browserWSEndpoint: "wss://browserless:3000"
});
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, F4ll0ut, how do you connect those two containers? have you created docker network or maybe you're using docker-compose?

Comment: @Vaviloff Hi, thanks for your response. I have created a docker network, added a screenshot to my post.

Comment: @Vaviloff found a solution. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Websocket secure, short wss was my issue. The following code works fine.

```
await puppeteer.connect({
  browserWSEndpoint: "ws://browserless:3000"
});
```